# What's wrong with this bash script using cut and sed (cut: command not found)?

Tags: bash

I'm getting server and path from an NFS location in bash as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

ST="/net/10.111.111.111/path/to/some/dir"
echo $ST
SERVER=$(echo $ST | cut -d'/' -f3)
echo $SERVER
PATH=$(echo $ST | cut -d'/' -f4-)
echo $PATH
PATH=$(echo $ST | cut -d'/' -f4-)
echo $PATH
```

The same 2 lines are repeated above on purpose.  The output is:

```
/net/10.111.111.111/path/to/some/dir
10.111.111.111
path/to/some/dir
./nn.sh: line 9: cut: command not found
```

I'm getting what I want but I don't understand why the second call to PATH= produces the above error.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`PATH` is a system variable which the `bash` shell uses to find where
your binaries(eg `cut`) are.

So, till :

```
PATH=$(echo $ST | cut -d'/' -f4-)
```

things work as expected. But after the command substitution ie `$(...)`, `PATH` points to a non-standard directory where bash could not find the standard binaries.

So the subsequent command :

```
PATH=$(echo $ST | cut -d'/' -f4-)
```

gave you the error :

```
./nn.sh: line 9: cut: command not found
```

**Moral**

Never use uppercase variables for your scripts as they are reserved for the system.

Comment: As just an addon, always check `env` for variables already reserved.

Comment: @Lidia : lol, Very true.. I have felt the after effects recently. ;)